# Linux (Mint) getting a cable internet connection

Tags: linux, dsl, cable-modem, linux-mint

I recently moved house and had my DSL connection downgraded to a cable connection. Anyway my Linux laptop is configured for a DSL connection. When I slip in the cat5 cable and try to connect to the net it wont let me in new house. 
The problem is I'm very new to Linux and I dont know the command for configuring a connection. I could configure the DSL connection using pppoeconf, but I dont know how to do it for a cable connection.

EDIT: I suspect the problem is that the machine is expecting a dsl connection. I am online now using a Win7 netbook which didn't need any configuring to switch.

Comment: Do you have a cable "modem"?

Comment: yes. whenever i use pppoeconf and try to setup a connection the system tells me I cant connect.

Comment: Doesn't your ISP provide instructions on how to connect? Do they use DHCP?

Comment: No. It's a long story. I moved house but the ISP contract at the new house is in the landlords name and has two months to run. The landlord cant get out of it so he said its free for two months and then I can sort out my own contract. I have no documentation from the ISP. Literally just walked into a house and stuck my computer into a modem and didnt get a connection.

Comment: Cable is almost always just DHCP as kobaltz answered. If that's not working, we'd need to know what the ISP is to research what they've done.

Comment: What did you mean "downgraded DSL to cable connection", isn't DSL uses cable? Or if you mean you used phone line then how coming to something else can be considered as downgrade, isn't it upgrade then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you can do without pppoe configuration with cable modems and just use their dhcp